# Verifying a pdf signature with Endesive raises an error when accessing SignerInfo native

Tags: python, pdf, python-cryptography, asn1crypto

I am trying to compare a signature with a certificate for a pdf file in python.
I found this very nice package called endesive.

I followed the example for verifying a pdf signature and I have something like this:

```
pdf_file_path = "/workspaces/test.pdf"
data = open(pdf_file_path, 'rb').read()
certificates = (
    open("/workspaces/certificates/pki.pem", 'rt').read(),
    open("/workspaces/certificates/pki-chain.pem", 'rt').read()
    )

(hashok, signatureok, certok) = pdf.verify(data, certificates)
print('signature ok?', signatureok)
print('hash ok?', hashok)
print('cert ok?', certok)
```

This should be pretty straight forward. I read the pdf, I open the certificates and then I 'pdf.verify' to see that everything is in order.

pdf.verify, at one point calls this: `signed_data = cms.ContentInfo.load(bcontents)['content'].native` which makes ans1crypto raise this error `File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asn1crypto/core.py", line 4060, in native raise e` repeatedly until it gets to

```
    ValueError: Unknown element - context class, constructed method, tag 0
    while parsing asn1crypto.core.Sequence
    while parsing asn1crypto.cms.SetOfAny
    while parsing asn1crypto.cms.CMSAttribute
    while parsing asn1crypto.cms.CMSAttributes
    while parsing asn1crypto.cms.SignerInfo
```

What could go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of addressing signer data info like this:

`signature = signed_data['signer_infos'][0].native['signature']`

It should have been addressed like this:

`signature = signed_data['signer_infos'][0]['signature'].native`

This has been addressed [here](https://github.com/m32/endesive/issues/122).